# Google Plus API Insert Moments not displayed

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using C# code to insert moments on User's Wall(It will be displayed in user's app's wall) but those are not being actually inserted. I am getting 200 response after insertion but that response has only 2 fields(kind & id) and no other fields(item, target etc.). I have read most of resources over internet but I think I am only soul who is facing this strange error.

I am pasting here plain http request-response

**Request**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: google-api-dotnet-client/1.9.1.12394 (gzip)
Authorization: Bearer <accesstoken>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 211
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

 {
   "target":
    {
     "name":"An example of add activity",
     "url":"https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/widget"
    },
   "type":"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
}
```

**Response** 200 OK

```
 {
  "kind": "plus#moment",
  "id": "Eg0xNDM3OTEwNzAwNDE2GPnkj6mg5b7Y7QEpg7DYUmwWVocyAhAUQgYYlcTmsSI"
 }
```

Important Things

1. My access_token is already generated by sending parameter `request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity` in auth url.
2. I am sending useremail and profile scope along with google plus login scope

Can somebody help me??

PS: One strange thing, I have seen that if I don't give "target.url" then I get "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: BTW [The Moments API is no longer supported as of May 29th, 2015](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/moments)

Comment: Yes. I also read that. So is there any other alternative? I have read that there are other "API Indexing" for android apps but I want to do it for a desktop app.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly same problem!
I get 200 Ok response with the following data:

```
{ kind: 'plus#moment',
  id: 'Eg0xNDM5ODAzNjQxNDE5GJL-wuqxjM_1FSm5JPhBE8KPMjICEBRCBxiH8r2wphs' }
```

and then I try to list moments and get 200 Ok response with data:

```
{ kind: 'plus#momentsFeed',
  etag: '"gLJf7LwN3wOpLHXk4IeQ9ES9mEc/6vRErVzx-PXyvghY9zcdoSrT-XU"',
  selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/101579422490714750738/moments/vault',
  title: 'Plus Moments Feed',
  updated: '2015-08-17T09:27:21.500Z',
  items: [] }
```

No moments or posts seen in my Google+ feed!!

Seems like this API does not work......

Any ideas? I've read the Indexing API is a replaceent, however I need my Web application to post moments on behalf of User, not android app.